# MYSQL - Multiple table join and SUM

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I'm facing problem with joining three tables and getting sum of its value I have three types of table Tax Types, Purchase Order and Purchase Items

currently I'm facing to get result of tax report kindly check below.

```
Tax Types
id  name        
1   No Tax      
2   VAT @10%    
3   GST @6%     
4   VAT @20%

Purchase Order
id  total   order_tax_id    order_tax   total_tax   grand_total
1   10.0000     1           0.0000      0.0000      10.0000
2   10.0000     2           1.0000      1.0000      11.0000
3   10.0000     3           0.6000      0.6000      10.6000
4   10.0000     4           2.0000      2.0000      12.0000
5   10.0000     1           0.0000      0.9100      10.0000
6   10.0000     1           0.0000      0.5700      10.0000
7   10.0000     1           0.0000      1.6700      10.0000
9   10.0000     2           1.0000      1.5700      11.0000

Purchase Items
id  purchase_id     tax_rate_id     item_tax    tax         subtotal
1   1               1               0.0000      0.0000      10.0000
2   2               1               0.0000      0.0000      10.0000
3   3               1               0.0000      0.0000      10.0000
4   4               1               0.0000      0.0000      10.0000
5   5               2               0.9100      10.0000%    10.0000
6   6               3               0.5700      6.0000%     10.0000
7   7               4               1.6700      20.0000%    10.0000
9   9               3               0.5700      6.0000%     10.0000
```

And the output should be like this

```
tax_name   sum_of_subtotal   sum_of_item_tax   sum_of_grand_total   sum_of_total_tax
VAT @20%    10.00            1.67    10.00     2.00                 3.67
VAT @10%    10.00            1.67    10.00     2.00                 3.67
No Tax      40.00            0.00    0         0                    0.00
GST @6%     10.00            1.67    10.00     2.00                 3.67
```

Kindly help me

Query I used

```
SELECT
tax_rates.name,                
(SUM(purchase_items.subtotal)) AS item_total_amount,
(SUM(purchase_items.item_tax)) AS item_tax_amount,
(SUM(purchases.grand_total) - SUM(purchases.order_tax)) AS total_amount,
(SUM(purchases.order_tax)) AS tax_amount
FROM tax_rates
LEFT JOIN purchases ON purchases.order_tax_id = tax_rates.id 
LEFT JOIN purchase_items ON purchase_items.tax_rate_id = tax_rates.id 
GROUP BY tax_rates.id
ORDER BY  tax_rates.name desc
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: tell us what query u write?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply kindly check I update the message

Comment: there's lots of redundancy here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue

```
SELECT
tax_rates.name,
purchase_item.subtotal AS item_total_amount,
purchase_item.item_tax AS item_tax_amount,
(purchases.grand_total - purchases.order_tax) AS total_amount,
purchases.order_tax AS tax_amount
FROM tax_rates
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.order_tax_id, SUM(a.order_tax) as order_tax, SUM(a.grand_total) as grand_total FROM purchases AS a  GROUP BY a.order_tax_id) AS purchases ON purchases.order_tax_id = tax_rates.id    
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.tax_rate_id, SUM(a.item_tax) as item_tax, SUM(a.subtotal) as subtotal FROM purchase_items AS a  GROUP BY a.tax_rate_id) AS purchase_item ON purchase_item.tax_rate_id = tax_rates.id
GROUP BY tax_rates.id
ORDER BY  tax_rates.name desc
LIMIT 0, 10
```